# Redshift loading data issue: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

```
SELECT s.store_id    AS store_key,
       s.store_id,
       a.address,
       a.address2,
       a.district,
       c.city,
       co.country,
       a.postal_code,
       st.first_name AS manager_first_name,
       st.last_name  AS manager_last_name,
       now()         AS start_date,
       now()         AS end_date
FROM staging_store s
JOIN staging_staff st   ON (s.manager_staff_id = st.staff_id)
JOIN staging_address a  ON (s.address_id = a.address_id)
JOIN staging_city c     ON (a.city_id = c.city_id)
JOIN staging_country co ON (c.country_id = co.country_id)
```

I am trying to load my pagila data into Redshift using the query above and I came into this error. Searched all over and still can't find a way around it.

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

What does it mean and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the Redshift error for referencing leader node information in a compute node based query - yes, it is a little cryptic.  This often happens when you references leader tables and try to join them with compute node tables.  But this isn't what you are doing.  In your case I believe that "now()" is a leader function and deprecated - you need to use "getdate()" instead.